# Generate a new item in an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a to-do list and I want each list item to have a number, starting from 1. I'm using the useState hook on the counter but I can't figure out how to add new items to the array every time I click on a button. I haven't coded in months and I'm really rusty.

```
function Product() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodo([...todo, input]);
    setCount(prevCount => [...prevCount, prevCount + 1]);

    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} type='text' />
        <button type='submit' onClick={addTodo}>
          Add!
        </button>
      </form>

      <h2 style={{ marginBottom: "0.5rem" }}>List of To-dos !</h2>

      {todo.map(todo => (
        <p>
          {count.map(count => (
            <p>{count}</p>
          ))}
          {todo}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to make it so each time I add a list item, it adds its number to the left. The first item would have 1, the second 2, etc..

Comment: There's no button in your code.

Comment: @Andy I didn't add the whole code, just the function where I want to generate a new number to the array

Comment: the map function gives you the index as the second argument.  So you can do count.map( (item, idx) => .....}).  Also you really should call the array "counts" not "count"

Comment: `prevCount => [...prevCount, prevCount + 1]` instead of incrementing `prevCount` (a Number) by 1, you are creating an Array. It's as simple as `prevCount=> prevCount + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really bad practice:

What you want to do is use the `index` param that Javascript map function gives you:

**Good practice**

```
todo.map((todo, index) => (
    <p>{index} - {todo}</p>
))
```

**Output**

```
0 - walk dog
1 - do yoga
```

Now if want the index to start at 1, you can simply add `+1` to `index`

```
todo.map((todo, index + 1) => (
    <p>{index} - {todo}</p>
))
```

**Output**

```
1 - walk dog
2 - do yoga
```

Since the index values are unique, you could use that to your benefit when performing other actions such as deleting etc. Usually you add the `key` attribute to the individual child values according to the official React documentation as follows

```
todo.map((todo, index + 1) => (
    <p key={index + 1}>{index} - {todo}</p>
))
```

where key is a unique value.

Also, change your variable names to something more meaningful.
I'd suggest changing `todo` to plurial `todos`.

Your final code should look like this:

```
function Product() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodo([...todo, input]);

    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} type='text' />
        <button type='submit' onClick={addTodo}>
          Add!
        </button>
      </form>

      <h2 style={{ marginBottom: "0.5rem" }}>List of To-dos !</h2>

      {todo.map((count, index + 1) => (
          <p key={index + 1}>{index} {todo}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This was EXTREMELY helpful, thank you so much for this perfect reply William.

Comment: That syntax looks alarming: `todo.map((todo, index + 1) => ...`

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

There's no reason to track the count of items in an array as its own separate state value.

1. Arrays have a `length` property which tells you the count of items in the array.
2. `.map()` includes an index in the callback, so if you just want to output the array index then you can do that.
3. You certainly don't need *an array of numbers* from 1-X in order to know the numbers from 1 to X.  The value of X alone gives you this information.

Remove the `count` state value entirely, and just output the index of the array from the `todo` list:

```
{todo.map((t, x) => (
  <p>
    {x}
    {t}
  </p>
))}
```

---

Note also that I abbreviated your inner `todo` variable to just `t`.  You can call it whatever you like, but giving it *the same name* as another variable you already have is just asking for confusion and bugs.

You may instead want to rename your array to something plural, like `todos`.  Then each item therein is semantically a `todo`:

```
{todos.map((todo, x) => (
  <p>
    {x}
    {todo}
  </p>
))}
```

Basically, names are important.  A variable/type/property/etc. name should tell you exactly and unambiguously what it is.  Poor variable names lead to confusing code, and being confused about your code is exactly what brought you here.